# Simulate click on cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I have an embedded blackboard session in a iframe. It is not important except that it is a cross-origin iframe.

I am interested in closing the modal that asks the user for microphone permissions through:

```
$('#techcheck-modal .close').click();
```

Sometimes the DOM element is available and sometimes it is not (as in the screenshot)

[image]

**$('#techcheck-modal .close').click();** works since I had the chance to test it and was a working solution. But only work when element is available in DOM.

Comment: It is impossible to programatically click on a cross origin iFrame. Also I would hate for you to allow the use of my peripherals, when the browser ask *ME* if *I* would allow it. HUGE Security risk

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is a popup advising me that I have the mic not allowed, and Blackboard advises me all the time that he wants access. Thats why.